# Move file in SQL server based on the beginning of the name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to copy certain file from a folder A to a folder B, but I need to copy only file based on a condition. The name of the file must start with the same value as a variable I have in my stored procedure.

Here is what I've got at the moment:

```
DECLARE @SQLFile VARCHAR(1024)
DECLARE @MessageId INT = 3 --copy all the files from the source folder that start with this variable

DECLARE @SourceFolderPath VARCHAR(1024)
DECLARE @DestinationFolderPath VARCHAR(1024)

SET @DestinationFolderPath = '\\mydestination'
SET @SourceFolderPath = '\\mysource'

SET @SQLFile = ' COPY /Y ' + @SourceFolderPath + ' /B ' + @DestinationFolderPath

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @SQLFile
```

With this code I copy all the files but I don't know if there is a way to integrate the condition of beginning of name.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a task for SQL Server; why are you trying to do it with it? This would be far better done in something like PowerShell.

Comment: this is why i use EXEC master..xp_cmdshell, i think !

Comment: No, you're using `xp_cmdshell` because you *want* to do it in SQL Server; as I mentioned this doesn't seem like a task to be done in SQL Server at all.

Comment: I agree with idea that tsql is an inappropriate tool, but the first set to automating this using the copy command is to actually write that command yourself at the command line to do what you want. If you can, then you should see the pattern that you need to adopt in the code that automates that manual process. So how do you copy a file (or are the multiple files - not clear) having a name that "starts" with something specific?

Comment: yeah but i need to integrate that as part of a stored procedure to get it done each time i call the stored proc !

Comment: `there is a way to integrate the condition` yes, don't use T-SQL for this. Use a Powershell script with filtering, wildcards etc. If you want to run a Powershell script on a schedule you can use SQL Server Agent.

Comment: @SMor in my folder, there will be always some files that start with the same value as my variable !

Comment: @MattRgx no you don't. Whatever you want to do, you don't want a stored procedure to weaken security and execute DOS commands. That's how you *assume* you can solve your real problem, whatever it is. What *is* the real problem? Transfer files periodically? Something else? Where does th database get involved? Is it the source of file paths?

Comment: @MattRgx just because a database is the source of some data doesn't mean *it* should also perform the job of external scripts. You can write a script that loads paths from a database and copies the files you want

Comment: ok so it's not possible to do it in t-SQL ?*

Comment: the stored proc will not be run on schedule, but sometimes depending of an action of a user.

Comment: Here's a single-line Powershell for you `Copy-Item -Path "\\mysource\3*" -Destination "\\mydestination"` If you really want to execute it from SQL, place that into a SQL Server Agent job and execute using `sp_start_job`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a simple file [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) will do what you want. But as people said in the comments **using [xp_cmdshell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=%20xp_cmdshell%20%28Transact-SQL%29%20%201%20Syntax.%20%202,server%20role%2C...%207%20See%20Also.%20%20More%20) can create all kinds of security issues if used where untrusted data is kicking about**. For this reason it is also often blocked by SQL Server security policy.

```
DECLARE @SQLFile VARCHAR(1024)
DECLARE @MessageId INT = 3 --copy all the files from the source folder that start with this variable

DECLARE @SourceFolderPath VARCHAR(1024)
DECLARE @DestinationFolderPath VARCHAR(1024)

SET @DestinationFolderPath = '\\mydestination'
SET @SourceFolderPath = '\\mysource'

SET @SQLFile = ' COPY /Y ' + @SourceFolderPath + '\' + CAST(@MessageID AS varchar(max)) + '* /B ' + @DestinationFolderPath

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @SQLFile
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've found a way to get it done with t-sql as i needed to get it done with t-sql.